# Loading DLLs not working when compiled c++, Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, dll, dllimport

I'm using the load library function to load 3 DLLs. The compiled code works fine when running inside Visual Studio:

[Picture From VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbE8K.png)
[image: Picture From VS]

But when running that same application (same exact file) from debug folder it fails:

[Picture From Debug Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Ga5.png)
[image: Picture From Debug Folder]

The code I'm using to load the DLL files is here:

```
#include <Windows.h>

HMODULE dll_cmn = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\LKG5000_DLL_ver1_10\\English\\64bit\\CmnLib.dll");
HMODULE dll_drv = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\LKG5000_DLL_ver1_10\\English\\64bit\\KeyUsbDrv.dll");
HMODULE dll_if2 = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\LKG5000_DLL_ver1_10\\English\\64bit\\LKIF2.dll");

cout << "\n>> Addr dll_cmn: " << dll_cmn << endl;
cout << "   Addr dll_cmn: " << dll_drv << endl;
cout << "   Addr dll_cmn: " << dll_if2 << endl;

if (NULL != dll_cmn && NULL != dll_drv && NULL != dll_if2)
{
    cout << "\n>> Created .dll Handles Successfully" << endl;
    //do stuff
}

else
{
    cout << "\n>> Failed to Create .dll Handles" << endl; 
}
```

I'm confused because the photos show the .exe is the same file in the same folderpath?

Any help would be really greatly appreciated!!

Comment: MCVE might help here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should call `GetLastError` and inspect the value returned.

Comment: Indeed. Check for errors. Don't be helpless. The system will tell you why it failed.

Comment: Sorry I should add that the "Success" and "Failed" are from my own cout in the program. There are no errors.

Comment: You don't do any error checking so you have no idea whether or not the system reports errors. Try reading the documentation for `LoadLibrary`. Read the section that describes the return value. It tells you what value is used to indicate failure, and how you can then go on to obtain extended information about the reason for the failure. That's your next step.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, please clean and build your project again, and then re-run it, view the result using two ways.

I just test it using the VS 2017 in my windows 64, I use three default dll files in the VS setup folder, they are all successful in the result window. If possible, you could test it in your side using my sample. At least, we could know that whether it is related to your VS Environment or the dll files themselves.

```
int main()
```

{

```
HMODULE dll_cmn = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\ReferenceAssemblies\\v4.5\\Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.dll");
HMODULE dll_drv = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\ReferenceAssemblies\\v4.5\\Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.Reasoning.dll");
HMODULE dll_if2 = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\ReferenceAssemblies\\v4.5\\Microsoft.Pex.Framework.dll");

cout << "\n>> Addr dll_cmn: " << dll_cmn << endl;
cout << "   Addr dll_cmn: " << dll_drv << endl;
cout << "   Addr dll_cmn: " << dll_if2 << endl;


if (NULL != dll_cmn && NULL != dll_drv && NULL != dll_if2)
{
    cout << "\n>> Created .dll Handles Successfully" << endl;
    //do stuff
}

else
{
    cout << "\n>> Failed to Create .dll Handles" << endl;
}

getch();
return 0;}
```

You could check the document about how to use the loadlibrary function and get error messages:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx

I also suggest you change the dll files folder, view the result. Or just use the x84 platform and run the process as the admin. View the result again.

Not very sure that whether it is related dependent dll file, but LoadLibrary will fail if any of the indirect linked-library is not available. So you also need to check that whether there are any changes for those dll files.

Comment: @Callum Alder, Would you please share us the latest information in your side?